Does the Okounkov-Vershik approach to the representation theory of $S_n$ shed new light on the problem of computing Kronecker coefficients?
I am studying the problem of decomposing tensor products of irreps of $S_n$. As a non-expert, I was surprised to see that this is an open problem, or a the very least, one for which no satisfactory combinatorial answer has been given. Please correct me if I missed something in the literature here.
I was wondering whether the Okounkov-Vershik approach makes this problem easier or more transparent.

I believe Igor Pak has lots of insights and/or strong opinions why one should not expect a nice answer. These coefficients are known to be hard to compute (but, so are the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients and they do have a rule, so who knows...)

Roughly the Okounkov-Vershik approach, via the Jucys-Murphy elements, exploits how the simple modules of the symmetric group behave under restriction. There is no indication that tensor products behave well under restriction, so I wouldn't expect Okounkov-Vershik to help with the Kronecker coefficients. This said, I'd be very happy to be proved wrong.

@PerAlexandersson Yes, Pak explains his point of view in What is a combinatorial interpretation?. See Section 9. He conjectures that the Kronecker coefficients are even harder to compute than the Littlewood-Richardson coefficients. Specifically, the latter are in #P, but Pak conjectures that the Kronecker coefficients are not even in #P.

I personally agree with Pak that we should not tacitly assume that there is no ignorabimus; i.e., that there must be a combinatorial interpretation, and we just have to work harder to find it. Whether Pak's proposal that #P is the right place to draw the line is IMO debatable, but if the Kronecker coefficients are hard for a complexity class larger than #P, then that would be good to know, and might not be that hard to prove. It would mean that any combinatorial interpretation would at least have to be "exotic".

Well the Okounkov-Vershik approach is close to 20 years old now, and it has been fairly well adopted by the community at large. So I won't say it could never help with the Kronecker coefficient problem, but if it were a silver bullet for solving it we would know by now.
Anyway here is in my mind what makes it hard to get at tensor products this way:
A group element $g$ acts on a tensor product by $g(u \otimes v) = gu \otimes gv$, but for a general element of the group algebra it is more complicated. In particular it is not so straightforward to figure out how the Jucys-Murphy elements act on a tensor product -- but analyzing how Jucys-Murphy elements act is an essential part of the Okounkov-Vershik approach.
